# not all categories being displayed

Tags: categories

I have created a child theme for a theme I purchased.  The purchased theme is for restaurants wanting to display their menu.  The theme accepts menu items as Posts, and groups them according to category.  The theme only accepts 1 level of categories, not more complex menus with 2 levels of categories.

The purchased theme is built for 1 level hierarchies. e.g:

```
>Menu
>>>Breakfast
>>>Lunch
>>>Dinner
```

However, the restaurant I am working for has a more complex menu:

```
>Menu
>>>Breakfast
>>>>>>Food
>>>>>>Sides
>>>>>>Drinks
>>>Lunch
>>>>>>Small
>>>>>>Large
>>>>>>Sides
```

My child theme aims to support two levels of categories.

Here is the portion of code which might be causing me problems:

```
<?php $args=array(
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'include' => '4, 5, 6, 27',
        //'exclude' => '3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26',
        'child_of' => $menuCat
        );
        $categories=get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category) {
                $catName = $category->name;
                $catName = strtolower($catName);
                $catName = str_replace (" ", "", $catName);
                $catName = str_replace ("&amp;", "", $catName);
                $catName = str_replace ("é", "e", $catName);
        ?>
        <div class="menuSection section" id="<?php echo $catName; ?>">
                <div class="titles"><h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2></div>
                <?php if($category->description){ ?>
                        <p class="catDescription"><?php echo $category->description; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php $args=array(
                'orderby' => 'slug',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'parent' => $category->term_id
                );
                $subcategories=get_categories($args);
                foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) {

                        $showPostsInSubCategory = new WP_Query();
                        $showPostsInSubCategory->query('cat='.$subcategory->term_id.'&showposts=100');
                ?>
...loop through display of subcategory
```

My [child theme](http://pastebin.com/LAdxP0rY) is an attempt to support 2 levels of categories.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/mzsHAQXC) is the original theme's index.php.

Even though I have hard-coded which categories to include, [the website](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/) only displays Posts for 1 category - Lunch.

**Why is Lunch the only category being displayed?**

Comment: You don't need to have both `include` and `exclude` in your `$args` array -- if you read [the documentation for `get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), `include` will include *only* the specified categories.

Comment: Thanks @PatJ.  I've removed the exclude parameter, but the issue remains - only 1 category is displayed.

Comment: Pastebins are discouraged in this site, you're expected to paste the code in the question. Also pasting whole files will likely not get an answer, you need to narrow the code down to the relevant parts so people can read it. Just some pointers on how to maybe get some answers.

Comment: try to rename the second `$args` to something like `$args2` I think you may be over writting your loop.

Comment: @Steve: Do you have any posts in these categories? Also remove the `include` part of this code - let's make it as simple as possible. Could you `var_dump` `$categories` variable just after setting it? @BandonRandom: I don't think this is the case in here. $args are only params for function - function already returned it's value...

Comment: Why to use a default cat-menu method? :o Why not you activate a custom menu for your site? It'll reduce all sort of problems like this. And a CSS for multi-level menu will let you show any complex level of menus. I think, as you have the privilege to fix the theme files, so you have the privilege to get rid of their codes and you can include your own code wherever you want. Na?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I think you've misunderstood it a little bit. Steve is talking about "menu" as list of dishes, and not about sites navigation ;)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż: take a look [now](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/).  If I remove the include statement, then the 2nd level categories are included in the navigation, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played with your code a little bit on my local WordPress. I think this should solve your problems.

Arguments for your first `get_categories` call, should look like this:

```
$args=array(
    'hide_empty'=>false,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    //'include' => '5, 6, 7, 8',   - you don't need to include anything
    //'exclude' => '3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26',   - no need to exclude anything either
    'parent' => $menuCat
);
```

And for the second one:

```
$args=array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'parent' => $category->term_id
);
```

It works correctly on my WP.

I also would recommend to use `<h3>` tags to display subcategories.

Comment: That worked, but I don't know why, as the other categories are not empty.

Comment: I haven't debug it to long, but maybe there is some conflict when you're using `include`, `child_of` and `hide_empty=>true` arguments... Or it works a little bit different than you/we assume. I'm glad my solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated the code and found that it will not work without the 'hide_empty' => false, and that it will also not work it you use the include with the child of.  Once these were modified your code worked in my sandbox.